# Documenting Spring's login/logout API in Swagger

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui, springfox

I am developing demo REST service using `Spring Boot` where user has to login in order to to perform certain subset of operations. After adding `Swagger UI` (using `springfox` library) with that simple configuration:

```
@Bean
public Docket docApi() {
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
            .select()
                .apis(any())
                .paths(PathSelectors.ant("/api/**"))
                .build()
            .pathMapping("/")
            .apiInfo(apiInfo())
            .directModelSubstitute(LocalDate.class, String.class)
            .useDefaultResponseMessages(true)
            .enableUrlTemplating(true);
}
```

I end up with all apis with all operations listed on `Swagger UI` page. Unfortunately I don't have login/logout endpoints listed among them.

The problem is that part of that operations cannot be performed via `Swagger UI` built-in form (I find it really nice feature and would like make it work), because user is not logged in. Is there any solution to that problem? Can I define manually some endpoints in `Swagger`?

If there was a form to submit credentials (i.e. login/logout endpoints) I could perform authorization before using that secured endpoints. Then, `Swagger` user could extract `token/sessionid` from response and paste it to custom query parameter defined via `@ApiImplicitParams`.

Below you can find my security configuration:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .formLogin()
                .loginProcessingUrl("/api/login")
                .usernameParameter("username")
                .passwordParameter("password")
                .successHandler(new CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler())
                .failureHandler(new CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler())
                .permitAll()
                .and()
            .logout()
                .logoutUrl("/api/logout")
                .logoutSuccessHandler(new CustomLogoutSuccessHandler())
                .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
            .csrf()
                .disable()
            .exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(new CustomAuthenticationEntryPoint())
                .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .and()
                .headers()
                .frameOptions()
                .disable();
}

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth
            .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
            .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A bit late for the party, but since SpringFox relies on Spring beans for building the documentation, we can easily manipulate it. Hope this can help someone!

Register it as a bean

```
@Primary
@Bean
public ApiListingScanner addExtraOperations(ApiDescriptionReader apiDescriptionReader, ApiModelReader apiModelReader, DocumentationPluginsManager pluginsManager)
{
    return new FormLoginOperations(apiDescriptionReader, apiModelReader, pluginsManager);
}
```

The class used to add any operation manually:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;

import com.fasterxml.classmate.TypeResolver;
import com.google.common.collect.Multimap;

import springfox.documentation.builders.ApiListingBuilder;
import springfox.documentation.builders.OperationBuilder;
import springfox.documentation.builders.ParameterBuilder;
import springfox.documentation.schema.ModelRef;
import springfox.documentation.service.ApiDescription;
import springfox.documentation.service.ApiListing;
import springfox.documentation.service.Operation;
import springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.DocumentationPluginsManager;
import springfox.documentation.spring.web.readers.operation.CachingOperationNameGenerator;
import springfox.documentation.spring.web.scanners.ApiDescriptionReader;
import springfox.documentation.spring.web.scanners.ApiListingScanner;
import springfox.documentation.spring.web.scanners.ApiListingScanningContext;
import springfox.documentation.spring.web.scanners.ApiModelReader;

public class FormLoginOperations extends ApiListingScanner
{
    @Autowired
    private TypeResolver typeResolver;

    @Autowired
    public FormLoginOperations(ApiDescriptionReader apiDescriptionReader, ApiModelReader apiModelReader, DocumentationPluginsManager pluginsManager)
    {
        super(apiDescriptionReader, apiModelReader, pluginsManager);
    }

    @Override
    public Multimap<String, ApiListing> scan(ApiListingScanningContext context)
    {
        final Multimap<String, ApiListing> def = super.scan(context);

        final List<ApiDescription> apis = new LinkedList<>();

        final List<Operation> operations = new ArrayList<>();
        operations.add(new OperationBuilder(new CachingOperationNameGenerator())
            .method(HttpMethod.POST)
            .uniqueId("login")
            .parameters(Arrays.asList(new ParameterBuilder()
                .name("username")
                .description("The username")
                .parameterType("query")            
                .type(typeResolver.resolve(String.class))
                .modelRef(new ModelRef("string"))
                .build(), 
                new ParameterBuilder()
                .name("password")
                .description("The password")
                .parameterType("query")            
                .type(typeResolver.resolve(String.class))
                .modelRef(new ModelRef("string"))
                .build()))
            .summary("Log in") // 
            .notes("Here you can log in")
            .build());
        apis.add(new ApiDescription("/api/login/", "Authentication documentation", operations, false));

        def.put("authentication", new ApiListingBuilder(context.getDocumentationContext().getApiDescriptionOrdering())
            .apis(apis)
            .description("Custom authentication")
            .build());

        return def;
    }
}
```

Rendering Swagger json:

```
"/api/login/" : {
      "post" : {
        "summary" : "Log in",
        "description" : "Here you can log in",
        "operationId" : "loginUsingPOST",
        "parameters" : [ {
          "name" : "username",
          "in" : "query",
          "description" : "The username",
          "required" : false,
          "type" : "string"
        }, {
          "name" : "password",
          "in" : "query",
          "description" : "The password",
          "required" : false,
          "type" : "string"
        } ]
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 8):

You can add a fake login and logout method in your API just to generate the Swagger documentation, it'll be automatically overriden by Spring Security filters.

```
@ApiOperation("Login.")
@PostMapping("/login")
public void fakeLogin(@ApiParam("User") @RequestParam String email, @ApiParam("Password") @RequestParam String password) {
    throw new IllegalStateException("This method shouldn't be called. It's implemented by Spring Security filters.");
}

@ApiOperation("Logout.")
@PostMapping("/logout")
public void fakeLogout() {
    throw new IllegalStateException("This method shouldn't be called. It's implemented by Spring Security filters.");
}
```

Comment: Thank You very match! Bless You!

Answer (score 5):

Just adding a little correction.
If you want to make real POST-request (through HTML page of swagger-ui for example), you need to make little changes to Morten's answer.

[Morten](https://stackoverflow.com/users/980178/morten-haraldsen)'s code makes POST request to /login like this:

`http://<hostname>/api/login?username=<user>&password=<password>`

But if you want to make a POST request you need to pass a body with it, not just query parameters.
To make that happen, you need to add parameter with name `body` and parameter type `body` like this:

```
@Override
public Multimap<String, ApiListing> scan(ApiListingScanningContext context)
{
    final Multimap<String, ApiListing> def = super.scan(context);

    final List<ApiDescription> apis = new LinkedList<>();

    final List<Operation> operations = new ArrayList<>();
    operations.add(new OperationBuilder(new CachingOperationNameGenerator())
        .method(HttpMethod.POST)
        .uniqueId("login")
        .parameters(Arrays.asList(new ParameterBuilder()
            .name("body")
            .required(true)
            .description("The body of request")
            .parameterType("body")            
            .type(typeResolver.resolve(String.class))
            .modelRef(new ModelRef("string"))
            .build()))
        .summary("Log in") // 
        .notes("Here you can log in")
        .build());
    apis.add(new ApiDescription("/api/login/", "Authentication documentation", operations, false));

    def.put("authentication", new ApiListingBuilder(context.getDocumentationContext().getApiDescriptionOrdering())
        .apis(apis)
        .description("Custom authentication")
        .build());

    return def;
}
```

Now we can pass a body with our POST request. A body could be JSON, for example:

`{"username":"admin","password":"admin"}`

Comment: Where should I put this code?

Comment: Accepted answer has all the code you need, I just made a little addition to make a correct POST request

Answer (score 1):

You can use an interface describing the authentication API. The acutal implementation is provided by Spring Security. (This a variation of [Italo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45385082/439171), where an interface is used instead of a fake implementation.)

```
/**
 * Authentication API specification for Swagger documentation and Code Generation.
 * Implemented by Spring Security.
 */
@Api("Authentication")
@RequestMapping(value = "/", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public interface AuthApi {
    /**
     * Implemented by Spring Security
     */
    @ApiOperation(value = "Login", notes = "Login with the given credentials.")
    @ApiResponses({@ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "", response = Authentication.class)})
    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    default void login(
        @RequestParam("username") String username,
        @RequestParam("password") String password
    ) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Add Spring Security to handle authentication");
    }

    /**
     * Implemented by Spring Security
     */
    @ApiOperation(value = "Logout", notes = "Logout the current user.")
    @ApiResponses({@ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "")})
    @RequestMapping(value = "/logout", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    default void logout() {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Add Spring Security to handle authentication");
    }
}
```

Comment: This will be my choice. But I don't see anything unless putting @Controller and also change the interface to public class AuthApi. Any idea?

Comment: i am also getting the same issue. any resolution?

Comment: Doesn't work without @Controller, also breaks default forms.

Answer (score 1):

My solution for springdoc-openapi:

```
@Bean
public OpenAPI customOpenAPI() {
    return new OpenAPI()
            .components(new Components())
            .tags(List.of(
                    new Tag()
                            .name("Authentication")
                            .description("Login/logout controller")
            ))
            .path("/logout", new PathItem()
                    .post(new Operation()
                            .tags(List.of(
                                    "Authentication"
                            ))
                            .summary("Logout")
                            .description("Logout the current user.")
                            .operationId("logout")
                            .responses(new ApiResponses()
                                    .addApiResponse("200", new ApiResponse().description("OK"))
                            )
                    )
            )
            .path("/login", new PathItem()
                    .post(new Operation()
                            .tags(List.of(
                                    "Authentication"
                            ))
                            .summary("Login")
                            .description("Login with the given credentials.")
                            .operationId("login")
                            .parameters(List.of(
                                    new Parameter().name("username").in("query").required(true).schema(new Schema().type("string")),
                                    new Parameter().name("password").in("query").required(true).schema(new Schema().type("string"))
                            ))
                            .responses(new ApiResponses()
                                    .addApiResponse("200", new ApiResponse().description("OK"))
                            )
                    )
            );
}
```