# How to expose Spring's HttpSecurity Logout endpoint in swagger-ui if using springdoc-openapi library?

Tags: spring, spring-security, swagger, swagger-ui, springdoc-openapi-ui

I have found solution for exposing Spring **logout** endpoint in swagger-ui for springfox:
[Configure Swagger-UI to pick up Spring's HttpSecurity Logout endpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36947117/configure-swagger-ui-to-pick-up-springs-httpsecurity-logout-endpoint)

but honestly don't know how to make it for springdoc-openapi:https://springdoc.org/

Answer (score 0):

You can use OpenApiCustomiser, and add the declaration of the endpooint programmatically to the OpenAPI Bean.