# OAuth2 authorization endpoint is not listed in Swagger using SpringFox

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, springfox

I use Spring Security 5 to build OAuth2 login and SpringFox for Swagger.

There is an endpoint `/oauth2/authorization/my-oauth`, but this endpoint doesn't appear in `/swagger-ui/`. How to let it appear in `swagger-ui`? The endpoint that requires login is also incorrect.

The endpoint works similar to redirect to Google/Facebook/Github login webpage that should be opened by browser, but Swagger shows

[image]

Already tried the solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/45921169/3952994 but it does not work and the endpoint still does not show up.

Related code:

```kotlin
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
class SwaggerConfig {
   
   @Bean
   fun api() = Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
      .select()
      .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
      .paths(PathSelectors.any())
      .build()
      .apiInfo(apiInfo())
```

```kotlin
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
class OAuth2SecurityConfig @Autowired constructor(
   private val myAuthRequestResolver: MyAuthRequestResolver,
   private val myAccessTokenResponseClient: MyAccessTokenResponseClient): WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter() {

   override fun configure(http: HttpSecurity) {
      http.authorizeRequests()
         .antMatchers("/v1/token**")
         .authenticated()
         .and()
         .csrf()
         .disable()
         .oauth2Login()
         .authorizationEndpoint()
         .authorizationRequestResolver(myAuthRequestResolver)
         .and()
         .tokenEndpoint()
         .accessTokenResponseClient(myAccessTokenResponseClient)
   }
}
```

```kotlin
   <parent>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.2.RELEASE</version>
      <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
   </parent>
       <dependency>
         <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
         <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
         <version>3.0.0</version>
      </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add `Authorization` header using below code

```
@Bean
public Docket api() {
    
    Docket docket = new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2).select()
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .apiInfo(apiInfo())
                .build()
                
        docket.globalRequestParameters(Arrays.asList(
                new RequestParameterBuilder().name("Authorization")
                        .description("Authorization details for security JWT token")
                        .in(ParameterType.HEADER).required(false).build()));
    return docket;
}
```

Comment: this is already there because I have @RequestHeader(name="Authorization") token: String in the controller parameters